# AngularJS $q.all update/notify not called why?

Tags: angularjs, q, angular-promise

So I have a simple example of using $q.all to batch $resource calls, what I want to know is why is my update handler never called?

I would have thought it would be called after each promise is successfully completed?

Only the result handler is called. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code snippet:

```
      var promises = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.mappedData, function(item) {
            var resource = new Resource(item);
            promises.push(resource.$save());
        });

        $q.all(promises).then(
            function(result) {
                console.log('result', result);

            },
            function(error) {
                console.log('error', error);

            },
            function(notify) {
                console.log('notify', notify);
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$q.all creates a new singular promise that once all the previous promises are complete will then continue on. If you want to do each one individually you'll have to reference them individually.

Comment: So it doesn't actually create a deferred object that calls the 'notify' method after each promise completes? That is what I thought but I guess not...

Comment: No, $q.all waits for ALL promises to complete.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I came with this solution. I've tried to arrange the code for your case.

```
var results = [], errors = [], d = $q.defer()
angular.forEach($scope.mappedData, function(item) {
    var resource = new Resource(item);
    resource.$save().promise
    .then(function (result) {
        results.push(result)
        if(results.length == $scope.mappedData.length)
            d.resolve(results) 
    }, function (err) {
        errors.push(err)
        results.push(null) // Very important =P
    }, function (notf) {
        d.notify(notf)
    })
})

d.promise.then(function (results) {
    console.log(results)
}, function (err) {
    console.error(err)
}, function (notf) {
    console.info(notf)
})
```

Let me know if it helps ;)