# Using $q and deferred.notify with $http calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I'm trying to build up and array of `$http.get` requests, then have promises run through them, and get progress notifications along the way.

I have the general idea of how to do it, but for some reason I just end up with all 20 HTTP calls being made and returning at the same time. The notify never gets run.

Basically for and Array of Things `['Thing1', 'Thing2', 'Thing3', ...]` I want to make an $http.get request. While this array of $http calls is being executed I would like to get current progress (1/3 finished) until all are finished and then run a function.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please provide examples of what you have attempted so that we can more easily assist you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per doc

> then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback) – regardless of when the promise was or will be resolved or rejected, then calls one of the success or error callbacks asynchronously as soon as the result is available

So basically let's have a bunch of promises

```
var req1 = $http.get('url1');
var req2 = $http.get('url2');
var req3 = $http.get('url3');
var req4 = $http.get('url4');
//do stuff when all of them are resolved
var promiseArray = [req1, req2, req3, req4];
$q.all(promiseArray).then(function(successResponse){ //success callback - it's ok
    //do stuff with my success execution
}, function(errorResponse){ //error callback - it has errors
    //throw exception
}, function(notificationResponse){ //notification callback - do stuff while executing
    //notify my stuff execution
});
```

This is it. Dead simple

As comment by @jusopi, it's worth noting that last callback (notification callback) will be called everytime a response gets success result.

> Additionally, the notify callback may be called zero or more times to provide a progress indication, before the promise is resolved or rejected.

For further readings refer to this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: that only _notifies_ after all of the promises have returned, not individually.

Comment: @jusopi nope, `Additionally, the notify callback may be called zero or more times to provide a progress indication, before the promise is resolved or rejected.` read [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: Curious. will notify continue to notify even if one of the requests fail until they all complete?

Comment: per your doc link "If any of the promises is resolved with a rejection, this resulting promise will be rejected with the same rejection value."

Answer (score 0):

#### pseudo-code

```
flags = 0

rqsts = [

    $http.get(url1)
    .then (rsp)->
        flags++
        rsp.data.data
    .catch (err)-> 
        # key here is to NOT reject but pass a successful failure
        # otherwise $q.all will bomb out
        err

    .....

    $http.get(urlN)
    .then (rsp)->
        flags++
        rsp.data.data
    .catch (err)-> 
        # key here is to NOT reject but pass a successful failure
        # otherwise $q.all will bomb out
        err
]

$q.all(rqsts)
```

Then in your UI you could watch the flags against the rqsts.length to see how many have completed.

**edit**

I've added an example to show how you can resolve/reject your individual requests to increment a counter while some are still pending.  It's in coffeescript & jade \ö/

codepen - http://codepen.io/jusopi/pen/admNmm?editors=101

## to be clear

It was stated in various comments and the other answer that:

> As comment by @jusopi, it's worth noting that last callback (notification callback) will be called everytime a response gets success result.
>
> Additionally, the notify callback may be called zero or more times to provide a progress indication, before the promise is resolved or rejected.

This is true only for singular instances of a promises.  In the question's context, this notification will only fire once **all** of the server requests have resolved.  It will not fire a notification for each server request as that is the responsibility of said server request.

Here is a related question/answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/28322945/1121919

Comment: Why do you even use coffeeScript for this kind of stuff?

Comment: Well technically it's pseudo-code and as for coffeescript vs javascript, I get sick of writing all the opening.closing brackets and parenthesis.  The logic is the same like most of the coding references on Wikipedia.

Comment: Don't you think that OP might not have knowledge of coffeescript or any other cool things that you know?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly doesn't matter really does it? answers on SO first and foremost are for the community, not specifically the op.

Comment: I'm not sure why the attitude, but it's rather juvenile.

Comment: @KevinB well, it's kinda stupid, to ask question in french and have an answer in japan, don't you think?

Comment: Not at all, it's psuedocode, that just so happens to somewhat look like coffee script. code is code.

Comment: The OP may or may not have knowledge of Coffeescript, but it's not just for them and it's also not like they wouldn't learn something moving forward.  Also in terms of readability, I think it's more concise and easier to follow than all the crazy bracketing.

Comment: I find coffeescript much harder to follow than "all the crazy bracketing".

Comment: Even it might had some reasons to live, it doesn't answer to question thought (in angular way!) So i find this discussion quite redundant!

Comment: Also note for @jusopi __I get sick of writing all the opening.closing brackets and parenthesis__ then don't even write anything. Do or do not. There is no try

Comment: it's basically equivalent to your code sample, other than the fact that it handles each request's error individually. @MedetTleukabiluly.

Comment: @KevinB nope, and i'm sure, and this conversation is getting quite stupid

Comment: just for the record, I am not going to be a jerk and downvote @MedetTleukabiluly's answer.. and I'd suggest others don't either.  It's not productive to the community/question in the least.

Comment: It's kinda unfair indeed, i feel like i've been robbed. My answer was quite directed to OP, your's was quite _strange_ way, anyway. This kind of stuff makes me sad. Especially from people like @KevinB who indeed must have understandings of QA, but kinda behaving weird with 60k.

Good luck in your life!

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly you shouldn't let one bad egg piss you off such, your answer was fine.